# Which dense inclusions of sites are ∞-dense?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, infinity-topos-theory, sites

An inclusion of sites f: D→C is *dense* if it induces an equivalence between the categories of sheaves on C and D.
Likewise, f is *∞-dense* is it induces an equivalence between the ∞-categories of ∞-sheaves on C and D.
An ∞-dense inclusion is dense but the opposite is false in general, see Counterexample 6.5.4.2 in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory.

A nontrivial example of an ∞-dense inclusion of sites is given by the inclusion Cart→Man
of cartesian spaces into all smooth manifolds, as explained in
[Is the site of (smooth) manifolds hypercomplete?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130999/is-the-site-of-smooth-manifolds-hypercomplete)

As it turns out, in the 1-categorical case we have an ample supply of dense inclusions of sites,
as explained by Proposition C2.2.16 of Johnstone's Sketches of an Elephant:
essentially small sites of definition of a given Grothendieck topos E that are subcanonical
can be identified with full subcategories of E whose objects form a separating family,
with the Grothedieck topology induced from the canonical topology on E.

Every inclusion of such sites is dense, but not necessarily ∞-dense.

I wonder if there is a (practical) criterion that allows us to check whether a dense inclusion is also ∞-dense.
We can assume the source site D to be hypercomplete, if necessary.

The example that I have in mind takes D to be the site of smooth manifolds (or cartesian spaces)
and C a subcategory of the category of sheaves of sets on smooth manifolds
that contains some infinite-dimensional smooth manifolds (e.g., smooth mapping spaces Map(M,N) between finite-dimensional manifolds).

**What additional conditions are needed to ensure that a dense inclusion of sites is ∞-dense?**

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of subcategory $C$ is allowed to be? Does it contain at least one $n$-manifold for all $n$ for example?

Comment: @DavidCarchedi: In the examples I have in mind C is supposed to be some category of infinite-dimensional manifolds, so in particular it contains all finite-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: In that case, as long as your infinite-dimensional manifolds are locally modeled on "convenient vector spaces" (e.g. Frechet spaces), then $f$ is infinity dense. I'm a bit busy this moment, but I will try to type up the proof soon.

Comment: @DavidCarchedi: Ok, thanks a lot for letting me know this.  I'm eagerly waiting for the details.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : I don't quite see how the counterexample you quote from HTT is a counter example of this. To me it is the typical counter example of a non-Hypercomplete infinity topos of sheaves. I don't see the connection with what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you content yourself with the hypercomplete case, a sufficient practical criterion is given in my paper joint with Tony Yue Yu, that you can find here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5166. The result we are concerned with is lemma 2.35.
It is the analogue of the well known result in algebraic geometry, that can be found here: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03A0.